# Find the order of $\bar{3}\in (\mathbb{Z}_{10}, \oplus)$ and the subgroup it generates

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Question:**
Find the subgroups $[\alpha]$ and $| \alpha |$, when $\alpha = \bar{3}\in (\mathbb{Z}_{10}, \oplus)$.

*Attempt:* I wrote the direct sum of $\bar{3}$ with elements of $\mathbb{Z}_ {10}$ and see what elements we generate.
For example:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{Z}_{10}=\{\bar{0},\bar{1},\bar{2},\bar{3},\bar{4},\bar{5},\bar{6},\bar{7},\bar{8},\bar{9},\}
\end{equation}
So...
\begin{equation}
\bar{3}\oplus \bar{0}= \bar{3}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\bar{3}\oplus \bar{1}= \bar{4}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\bar{3}\oplus \bar{2}= \bar{5}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\bar{3}\oplus \bar{3}= \bar{6}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\bar{3}\oplus \bar{4}= \bar{7}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\bar{3}\oplus \bar{8}= \overline{11}=\bar{1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\bar{3}\oplus \bar{9}= \overline{12}=\bar{2}
\end{equation}

So the subgroup generated by $\bar 3$ of $\mathbb{Z}_ {10}$ is the set formed by the elements $\bar{3},\bar{4},\bar{5},\bar{6},\bar{7},\bar{1},\bar{2}$.
As for the subgroup order, I don't know ... can someone help me? Is this the number of elements in the subgroup?

Comment: To me, $[\alpha]$ denotes an equivalence class; $\lvert \alpha\rvert$, the order of $\alpha$. Please define your notation.

Comment: Of course. I will put.Thanks.

Comment: But you did not answer my question.

Comment: I can't do that without knowing what you mean by $[\alpha]$ and $\lvert\alpha\rvert$. Your question suggests that each is a subgroup of $(\Bbb Z_{10},\oplus)$. That notation is certainly not standard, if so.

Comment: Oh sorry. But it's the same as you said, that notation.

Comment: If you can help me, I'll be grateful.

Comment: What equivalence relation is $[\alpha]$ with respect to, then?

Comment: I'd be happy to help; I just need clarification.

Comment: What exactly is going on here? If you are considering $\mathbb Z / 10 \mathbb Z$ as an additive group, then the order of the subgroup generated by $\overline n$ is just the least positive integer $k$ such that $10 \,|\, kn$ because the $k$-fold sum of $n$ is nothing more than $\overline{kn}.$

Comment: [$\alpha]$ means the subgroup.

Comment: Do you mean to suggest, perhaps, that $[\alpha]$ is the subgroup *generated by $\alpha$*? If so, $\langle\alpha\rangle$ is the standard notation.

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be that you want to know the cyclic subgroup generated by $\bar3$, and the order of that subgroup.

The subgroup is $\langle\bar3\rangle=\{\bar3,\bar6,\bar9,\bar2,\bar5,\bar8,\bar1,\bar4,\bar7,\bar0\}$.  Thus it is the whole $\Bbb Z_{10}$, and has order $|\langle\bar3\rangle|=10$.

This is essentially because $3$ and $10$ are coprime.

Comment: How to generate $\bar{0}$ and $\bar{9 }$ by direct sum with $\bar{3}$?

Comment: Could you answer me please?

Comment: Fernanda, I don't quite follow